# Why this script in cron.daily won't run?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I wrote this small Python script to make daily backups of a directory containing some files (the backups should rotate after one week). This is it:

```
$ cat /etc/cron.daily/file-store-backup.py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import datetime
import calendar
import subprocess
import os.path

def main():
    origin = '/var/file-store'
    today_name = calendar.day_name[datetime.date.today().weekday()]
    dest = '/var/file-store-backup/' + today_name

    if os.path.exists(dest):
        subprocess.call(['rm', '-rf', dest])

    subprocess.call(['cp', '--reflink=always', '-a', origin, dest])
    subprocess.call(['touch', dest])

    last = open('/var/file-store-backup/LAST', 'w')
    print(today_name, file=last)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when I run it manually, it works as expected, creating a backup directory named after current week's day, but it is not being run daily: I left it inside /etc/cron.daily for 3 days and after that no backup directory was created, the server was on all time.

The permissions are right:

```
$ ls -l /etc/cron.daily/file-store-backup.py 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 553 Abr 11 17:19 /etc/cron.daily/file-store-backup.py
```

The system is Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS and the cron configuration was not tampered with since installation.

Why the script is not being run?

Comment: check `/var/log/cron.log` and search for the script name - `file-store-backup.py` and see if there are any errors in the cron log.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because your script has a `.py` extension. The files in `/etc/cron.daily` are run by the [run-parts(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/run-parts.8.html) command and it's default is to ignore programs that don't match various rules. You should be able to just remove the `.py` extension.

> run-parts  runs  all  the  executable  files  named  within constraints
>          described  below,  found  in  directory  directory.   Other  files  and
>          directories are silently ignored.
>
> If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then
>          the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters,
>          ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.

For example

```
touch /etc/cron.daily/test.py
chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/test.py
run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/apache2
...
```

no sign of test.py

```
mv /etc/cron.daily/test.py /etc/cron.daily/test
run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily 
/etc/cron.daily/apache2
...
/etc/cron.daily/test
```

ta da !

Comment: the `run-parts --test /etc/cron.d` is a life-saver, forgot the `chmod +x` :/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the cron entry look like 
`0 * * * 1-7 root /etc/cron.daily/file-store-backup.py`

I don't usually put the actual script in the cron file, usually I refer to the script in the file.

Comment: Take a look in /etc/cron.daily and be educated.